# Are the featurette classes in Bootstrap 3 in css by default, or do I have to add them manually?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to copy the typography from the featurette section on [this](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/) page. I put all the featurette classes in, but all that shows up is the featurette-divider.

Here is my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mockup</title>
    <?php include 'inc/head.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr class="featurette-divider">
                <div class="featurette featurette-shadow">
                    <h2 class="featurette-heading">Testing 1...2...3... <span class="text-muted">Lets Go!</span></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but here is some CSS that might help you...

```
 .featurette-divider {
  margin: 80px 0; /* <hr> between each */
}
 .featurette {
  padding-top: 120px;
  overflow: hidden; /* Clear floats */
}
 .featurette-image {
  margin-top: −120px; /* Vertically center image with the text */
}
 .featurette-heading {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
 .featurette-image.pull-left {
  margin-right: 40px;
}
 .featurette-image.pull-right {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question title in short: no, you have to include them manually.

Nothing stops you adding your own styles or third party style bundles to your project. Simply include them after your bootstrap css.